# Как определить глубину рекурсии моей функции

Tags: golang, рекурсия

И снова с рекурсией.
На этот раз пытаюсь понять, как определять глубину рекурсии

Задача: на ввод подается последовательность из натуральных чисел, нужно определить среднее этой последовательности.

Условие: Использовать только рекурсию.

Мое решение:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%f", rec(0, 0))
}

func rec(sum, count float64) float64 {
    x := 0.0
    fmt.Scan(&x)
    if x == 0 {
        return sum / count
    }
    return rec(sum+x, count+1)
}
```

Задался вопросом, какова глубина рекурсии у моего решения. Предполагаю, что глубина рекурсии данной функции будет равна переменной `count`. В таком случае, вижу потенциальное переполнение стека, если последовательность будет продолжаться бесконечно. Если мое прежположение вернО, то как подчищать стек после каждого вызова, чтобы он не раздувался?

Пытался сделать `strace -k go run .` и при вводе чисел "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0" получаю вывод

```
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x70b63]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0xebe7]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x4042c]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x41d5c]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x42b51]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x43a66]
 > /usr/lib/go-1.21/bin/go() [0x6cece]
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Но не понимаю, что он значит. По идее `-k` выводит стек после каждого вызова. Значит ли этот вывод, что стек все таки не раздувается?

UPD:

На основе ккомментариев пошел читать про хвостовую рекурсию и нашел такое пример, при котором хвостовая рекурсия не будет оптимизирована.

[image: Пример отсутствия оптимизиции]

И на основе этого примера, слегка, отредактировал свой код до вида:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%f", rec(0, 0))
}

func rec(sum, count float64) float64 {
    x := 0.0
    fmt.Scan(&x)
    if x == 0 {
        return sum / count
    }
    return 1 * rec(sum+x, count+1)
}
```

Сделало ли это рекурсию не оптимизируемой и как узнать, оптимизируется ли моя рекурсия до итерации?

UPPD

Начал читать sicp и там так же пишут(по мне вполне справедливо и обосновано), что древовидная рекурсия порождает кратно больше рекурсивных вызовов, чем даже линейная. На каких вообще данных древовидная рекурсия будет полезна? Не пойму что-то зачем же она нужна.

[image: Абзац про древовидное вычисление фибоначи]

алгоритм древовидной рекурсии про который идет речь в абзаце на скрине выше:

[image: алгоритм древовидной рекурсии про который идет речь в абзаце]

и схема порождения вызовов в древовидной рекурсии. На ней видно что `fib 1` вызывается аж 5 раз и с остальными `fib x` ситуация не лучше...
[image: Схема]

Comment: Глубина стека равна количеству чисел, верно. Некоторые компиляторы удаляют концевую рекурсию - у вас именно такая, но про компилятор go не знаю.

Comment: если компилятор удаляет концевую рекурсию,  то глубина этой будет равна count-1?

Comment: Если удаляет, то её вообще не будет, в скомпилированном коде тело функции превратится в цикл

Comment: а как именно увидеть, превратилась ли она в цикл? и вообще, хорошо ли это и удовлетворяет ли условию задачи "использовать только рекурсию", если в итоге она стала циклом.(при условии что компилятор удаляет концевую рекурсию)

Comment: Как увидеть в go - не знаю, промежуточного кода там же нет, только ассемблерный листинг смотреть. А условию удовлетворяет - вы код сделали с рекурсией, а дальше дело компилятора.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Новое после UPD

Comment: Глубина рекурсии != глубина стека. 

Глубина рекурсии - это абстрактная величина, равная максимальной длине цепочки вызовов. Глубина стека - это конкретная величина, которая очень сильно зависит от особенностей компилятора. Например, если компилятор умеет обрабатывать концевую рекурсию, то стек вообще расти не будет. Но на глубину рекурсии это не влияет.

Comment: Тривиальные операции вроде `1 * ` компилятор выбросит. Если хотите испортить хвостовую оптимизацию, вычисления надо перенести из аргументов функции на её результат.

Comment: Вид рекурсии определяется задачей/реккурентной функцией. То что ради сокращения глубины стека некоторые товарищи переделывают линейную рекурсию в древовидную - это трюк, не более.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. На моём компиляторе стек в вашей программе переполняется:

> ```
> $ seq 10000000 -1 0 | go run temp.go
> runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
> fatal error: stack overflow
> ...
> ```

Это видно и по потреблению памяти в мониторе. С оптимизированной хвостовой рекурсией память не должна расти. А она растёт.

2. Если оставаться в рамках линейной рекурсии, стек нельзя подчистить. Можно переделать в древовидную. Программа будет страшная (или красивая - кому как) но будет использовать логарифмический от количества чисел размер стека. Глубины стека в 500 рекурсивных вызовов хватит до тепловой смерти вселенной.
3. Ваша попытка сделать рекурсию неоптимизируемой повеселит компилятор, но ничего не изменит. Можно сделать так:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sum, count := rec()
    fmt.Printf("%f", sum / count)
}

func rec() (float64, float64) {
    x := 0.0
    fmt.Scan(&x)
    if x == 0 {
        return 0, 0
    }
    sum, count := rec()
    return sum + x, count + 1
}
```

**P.S.** Вычисление среднего через древовидную рекурсию. Переполнить стек нереально.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func treeRec(depth int) (bool, float64, int) {
    if depth == 0 {
        x := 0.0
        fmt.Scan(&x)
        if x == 0 {
            return true, 0, 0
        }
        return false, x, 1
    }
    done1, sum1, count1 := treeRec(depth - 1)
    if done1 {
        return done1, sum1, count1
    }
    done2, sum2, count2 := treeRec(depth - 1)
    return done2, sum1 + sum2, count1 + count2
}

func linearRec(depth int) (float64, int) {
    done, sum1, count1 := treeRec(depth)
    if done {
        return sum1, count1
    }
    sum2, count2 := linearRec(depth + 1)
    return sum1 + sum2, count1 + count2
}

func main() {
    sum, count := linearRec(0)
    fmt.Printf("%f", sum / float64(count))
}
```

**P.P.S** Не воспринимайте этот код серьезно. Да, хорошо что есть средства, которые позволяют работать с рекурсией в языках без оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии. Но, нет, никто так не делает на практике. Это лишь упражнение для вашего ума. На Go вместо линейной рекурсии пишите цикл и всё будет хорошо.

Comment: Странно. Читаю про древовидную рекурсию и написано, что она как раз больше вызовов делает и быстрее стэк переполняет. 

[here](https://studopedia.ru/29_79740_lineynaya-i-drevovidnaya-rekursii.html

Comment: @Quester, вы нашли плохую статью. Я с первого просмотра нашел две фактические ошибки. Одна про переполнение стека в древовидной рекурсии.

Comment: да, я понимаю, что такие задачи необязательно решать через рекурсию(даже может быть нежелательно), но я пытаюсь разобраться в рекурсии, чтобы быть хорошим программистом и не впасть в ступор, когда столкнусь с древовидной рекурсией и хочу уметь в нее.

Comment: @Quester, знать и уметь хорошо, добро пожаловать в клуб. Технология сокращения глубины стека путем переделки рекурсии мне пригодилась два раза: тут и ещё раз тут в другом вопросе.

Comment: А может вы знаете ресурс, где можно почитать хорошие статьи и другую инфу, чтобы научиться в рекурсию? сейчас слабо понимаю рекурсию, целый день сижу и пытаюсь врубиться в рекурсию в quickSort. Пока что врубился только в хвостовую рекурсию, а все остальное мне прям тяжело дается. А хотелось бы и в древовидную.

Comment: Отыщите перевод SICP на русский или напишите мне, я перешлю копию. Трёх первых глав будет достаточно.

Comment: sicp начал читать и появились снова вопросы к древовидной рекурсии. ОБновил вопрос